# Using Jasmine with Angular JS input validation

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs, jasmine

I have an angularjs app, which validates certain input fields. I was looking to write unit tests via Jasmine to test and maintain the validity of these fields.

NOTE: The validation works fine normally, just with jasmine, it doesn't seem to update.
The unit tests have no syntax errors, but simply result in:

```
Error: Expected false to equal true.
   at new jasmine.ExpectationResult
   at null.toEqual
   at null.<anonymous>
   at jasmine.Block.execute
   at jasmine.Queue.next_
   at chrome-extension
```

For instance, I have, in the directives:

```
}).directive('billingNumberPopup', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        scope.$watch(
                function() {
                    return ctrl.$viewValue;
                }, 
                function(value){
                    numValidation(value);
                }
            );
        function numValidation(viewValue){
            if (!viewValue || viewValue == "" ||  (!viewValue.toString().match(/[a-z]/gi) && viewValue.toString().match(/[0-9]/g).length == 6)){
                ctrl.$setValidity('billingNumber',true);
            }
            else
            {
                ctrl.$setValidity('billingNumber',false);                   
            }
```

and then from my unit tests...

```
    it('Check if validation works', function(){
    var len = $scope.dataToPost.length;
    $scope.addRow();
    console.log("Hi");
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.dataToPost[len].billingNumber = "HELLO";});
    $scope.$apply();
    console.log($scope.dataToPost[len].billingNumber);
    console.log($("input[ng-model='d.billingNumber']"));    
    expect($("input[ng-model='d.billingNumber']")[len].classList.contains("ng-invalid")).toEqual(true);

});
```

where "HELLO" is not a valid billing number, and `scope.dataToPost` is the data that is binded to the input fields. I would assume, that changing the value, and calling `$scope.$apply` would trigger validation, any suggestions?

Comment: My understanding is that directives are a bit of a pain in the ass to unit test.  Perhaps moving your validation tests into the e2e testing would be easier?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for steering me in the right direction. Although it would have been nice for Jasmine to be able to test directives, I guess I'll go with e2e for testing directives. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2):

The jasmine error indicates that you are trying to access a null object.

This appears to occur when you are accessing the `len` instead of the `len - 1` index of the array. Try changing the expectation to:

```
expect($("input[ng-model='d.billingNumber']")[len - 1].classList.contains("ng-invalid")).toEqual(true);
```